# What does the notation $E_{X_n}$ with $X_n$ a random variable refers to?

Tags: probability, notation, conditional-probability

Context : Conditionnal probabilities : Markov Properties (strong or weak)
What is the meaning of the notation  $E_{X_n}[Y] $ with $ X_n,Y$ random variables ?

Found many courses using this notation without introduction , does it refer to $E[Y,\sigma(X_n)]$ ?

Comment: I'd assume $E_{X_n}[Y]$ is an abuse of notation for the conditional expectation $E[Y|X_n=x_n]$, or for the random variable $E[Y|X_n]$, a function of $X_n$. What does $E[Y,\,\sigma(X_n)]$, or more generally $E[Y,\,a]$, mean?

Answer (score -2):

$E_{X_n}(Y):\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R},w\rightarrow E_{X_n(w)}[Y]=E_{P(.|X_0=X_n(w))}[Y]$